# How do I fix this moment js bug in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

I've created a `posts` model in Mongoose, that records all posts created by users.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const moment = require('moment')

const postSchema = new Schema({
// Other fields in DB

timeCreated:{
type:String,
default: moment().valueOf()
}

});

const Posts = mongoose.model('Posts', postSchema);
module.exports = Posts
```

The exact part of the code I'm having problems with is this one here:

```
timeCreated:{
type:String,
default: moment().valueOf()
}
```

I'm using the `timeCreated` object to make time calculations in the front-end. So, when users create posts, the database will indicate that the posts were created at the same time, even if the posts where created hours apart.

See the database snapshot (emails and usernames are fake):

[image: database snapshot 1]

[image: database snapshot 1]

If you look closely, the `timeCreated` object carries the same string value in all 4 posts, regardless of the fact that the posts were created hours apart.
Is there something wrong with my code, or is this a Mongoose/Moment js bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in my application, I did this to fix it.
I have lost the link where my problem was solved.

```
timeCreated:{
     type:String,
     default: () => moment().valueOf()
}
```

PS: I think you will be better of using default Javascript Date instead of `moment`, As they themselves are asking out to switch to a different alternative.
[Read here.](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

Something like this.

```
timeCreated:{
     type:String,
     default: () => new Date()
}
```